# Why does this JavaScript not always work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using custom `data-` elements with jQuery.

Here is HTML:

```
<div id="chat" data-chat-name="room1">room1</div>
<div id="chat" data-chat-name="room2">room2</div>
```

Here is jQuery:

```
<script>
$("#chat").click(function(event){
    document.getElementById("1").contentWindow.sendCommand("JOIN #" + $(this).attr('data-chat-name'));
});
</script>
```

The problem I am having is that it only works if you click on the first `<div>` i.e. room1, any other clicks are ignored. Why is this? i.e. if I click on room2, nothing happens, but when I clicked on room1 it works.

Comment: The `id` must be unique. You can't use the same `id` multiple times in the same document.

Comment: I don't want different ids, there's no need.... otherwise I need to set up listener for 400+ ID's!!!

Comment: Yes there is need. As @cezar wrote, "You can't use the same `id` multiple times in the same document."

Comment: so i have to write 400+ seperate jquery listener for clicks for all 400+ ids??!

Comment: No you don't, use `class="chat"` and bind to `$(".chat")` instead.

Comment: A `class` *as well* as an `id` can **both** be used in CSS **and** JS my friend - the only difference is that an `id` **has** to be unique whereas a `class` doesn't have to be unique.

Comment: class was meant for CSS though, even if it works in this scenario it wasn't meant for it, the docs even say so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment starting with

> I don't want different ids, theres no need...

- it seems you misunderstand what an `ID` is.

An `ID` is a unique identifier **only to be used with one element** and **one** element only, you have no choice here. The JS will keep failing as long as you have the *same* `ID`'s so I would listen to the commenters, they know what they are doing here.

Instead of using an `ID` I recommend you use a `class` instead

a `class` can occur on as many elements as required so you can use the same one for your 400+ elements.

Your selector would become `$('.chat').click(...snipped...);`

with HTML:

```
<div id="chat1" class="chat" data-chat-name="room1">room1</div>
<div id="chat2" class="chat" data-chat-name="room2">room2</div>
```

There's nothing more to it. People decided back when they created this  system that an `ID` is to be used on one element and a `class` is to be used on multiple even tho a class works perfectly fine on one element too, if you think you can change that you're naive - no offence intended there btw but I feel like I have to pry your eyes open after seeing your statement that I **quoted** at the top of this post.

Good luck with this, it will solve your issue and make you a better developer since you'll be using the **right** technique for the **right** reason in the **right** place.

Comment: Accepted since it does work, docs say class should be used for css though. Thanjs

Comment: @user5603796 can you link me these *docs* that are telling you this because if that is the case they aren't doing a good job at web-development at all and if more people read these docs they will also get wrong information too, glad it helped you out and I hope I did not offend you while at it in my answer :)

Answer (score 5):

1st Ids must be unique ..use classes instead .. so you can start from here

```
<div class="chat" data-chat-name="room1">room1</div>
<div class="chat" data-chat-name="room2">room2</div>
```

and in js

```
<script>
$(".chat").click(function(event){
    alert($(this).attr('data-chat-name'));
    // with data attr you can use  .data() as well
    alert($(this).data('chat-name'));
});
</script>
```

**Additional informations** you may need if you have different Ids

```
 <div id="chat1" data-chat-name="room1">room1</div>
 <div id="chat2" data-chat-name="room2">room2</div>
```

you can use a selector `$('[id^="chat"]')` .. that mean select all elements there Ids starts with chat

Answer (score 1):

id element should be unique. Therefore it is returning the first id. you should use class instead of id.

Answer (score 0):

IDs must be unique. Use classes instead.

```js
$(".chat").click(function(event) {
  console.log('hi');
  // document.getElementById("1").contentWindow.sendCommand("JOIN #" + $(this).attr('data-chat-name'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chat" data-chat-name="room1">room1</div>
<div class="chat" data-chat-name="room2">room2</div>
```